# Need to create XML using JAXB for java key-value object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

Below is my java class structure having key value pair like in Hashmap

```
public class Property {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public Property(){

    }

    public Property(String key,String value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Property [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
        properties.add(new Property("key1","value1"));
        properties.add(new Property("key2","value2"));
        properties.add(new Property("key3","value3"));
        properties.add(new Property("key4","value4"));      
    }


}
```

From the above java object structure, i want to create below xml structure using JAXB or any other alternate solution using java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<properties>
    <key1> value1 </key1>
    <key2> value2 </key2>
    <key3> value3 </key3>
    <key4> value4 </key4>
</properties>
```

Please suggest your solution using JAXB or other alternative solution

Thanks in advance
Vivek Shah

Comment: You are creating XML representations of data classes already initialized, this is called marshalling in JAXB terminology. Google it.

Comment: Here is how you can map your use case using EclipseLink MOXy: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html

Comment: why dont you use <key name="key1"> value1 </key>